# Updating a React App hosted on Google Cloud Storage getting 404 errors

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-storage

I've hosted a React App on GCS, and it works alright. However, occasionally after I deployed new code I would get 404 errors on some js files that's been code splitted by webpack. When I check my storage bucket, however, I can verify that the file exists but cannot access it directly. This problem always happens for about an hour and then my site is back to normal.

I have set all my files to be public, and here's my deployment script:
`"env-cmd -f .env.staging.local react-scripts build && gsutil rsync -R -d build gs://mysite && gsutil setmeta -h \"Cache-Control:no-cache, max-age=0\" gs://mysite/index.html"`

This is very confusing and hard to debug as I can see that the file exists but for some reason it's not being read by index.html. Also I've tried to clear the edge cache so maybe it's not a cache issue either?

[image]

Comment: I would like to know if the React App that you have hosted on GCS is static or not. In case is not statis I would highly recommend you to deploy it using Google App Engine, but to continue investigating further, it would be great to know if the website you have hosted is static. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My site is static and I've got my Node backend hosted on cloud run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting and researching, it seems like  a caching issue with the way I'm deploying my code to Cloud Storage. I've updated my deployment code in order to avoid js being "cache from disk".

`react-scripts build && gsutil -h \"Cache-Control:no-cache, max-age=0\" rsync -R -d build gs://mysite`